# Using JS or AJAX to live search filter through JSON object on page (laravel)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, laravel

I'm new to AJAX and a lot of JS, but I need to replace some old angular functionality on our Laravel site.

We simply have a page with a static/sticky header search bar, but no submit button. It needs to do a live filter upon search input. i.e. if I type sofa, it should hide anything from the page without the word sofa.

The Laravel blade/HTML is built with foreach loops from controller data, but more importantly, the data is stored in a JSON object called `orderFormData`, shown below.

I need a simple and effective live search filter to hide anything that doesn't match between the JSON and the search bar. The page is built with multiple HTML tables so I don't want to filter by the table and I think that's too complicated and convoluted. It should suffice to do it by JSON, possibly with AJAX. However, I'm a total novice here and I'm desperate for a solution.

Here's the search html:

```
<div class="md-input-wrapper search-form">
            <form class="uk-search" id="searchProducts">
                <input type="text" class="md-input label-fixed" name="srch-term" id="srch-term" autofocus placeholder="Search Products"/>
                <span class="md-input-bar"></span>

            </form>
        </div>
```

Here's the JSON object and some JS that I was playing with, but it doesn't work:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
var orderFormData = <?php echo json_encode ($tempdata);?>;

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#srch-term').on('keyup',function(){
    var searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('.uk-table tbody tr').each(function(){
        var lineStr = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        if(lineStr.indexOf(searchTerm) === -1){
            $(this).hide();
        }else{
            $(this).show();
        }
      });
  });
});
</script>
```

This is just a pure JS idea, but I'm interested in AJAX as well if it will work better for this scenario. How can I properly filter items on the page by tying the search bar and JSON object?

Comment: This is not pure JS, this is jQuery.

Comment: I should have specified, sorry. I'm fine with pure js or jquery, the only thing is it can't be angular because it's been removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need of Ajax to do a search function with hide and show, this is simply manipulating DOM, instead ajax can calls the json from the php and with jquery you can simple loop your td on keypress and use :contains of jquery, onkeypress you call a function and in this function you do show and hide if contains "search" show otherwise hide.
Here a simple example in one of my old project #tabellaWebLog was the id of the table ricercaUser was the id of the input search and trTabellaWebLog was the id of the row where i wanted the search instead .ricUser was the class of the table column to loop the search inside the table...Bye

```
user = $('#ricercaUser').val();
$('#tabellaWebLog').find("#TrTabellaWebLogRiga:not(:contains('"+ user +"'))").hide();   
$(".ricUser:contains('" + user + "')").parent().show();
$(".ricUser:not(:contains('" + user + "'))").parent().hide();
```